# Displaying my own iad in application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

I want to displaying my own ads in my applications. Acutally the ads banner are static images which are loaded after some delay. Is iad network should be enable for that the app which display these iads. Because i does not want to load iads from the apple.

Comment: the content for the `ADBannerView` comes from the Apple. you cannot override the content... but you can get feedback about any iAd content is posted to your application or not, and when the empty `AdBannerView` is hided, you can show a simple `UIView` with _custom content_ until the `ADBannerView` must be shown again with new content which came from the Apple again. the phrase _custom content_  does not suggest advertising, of course.

Comment: Hi Holex, Even i want to display my sponsors as ads in my iphone app.Can you please help me out by guiding me with the best way.Thanks in Advc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. iAd is only for displaying ads from the Apple iAd network using an `ADBannerView` in your app. If you are just presenting the user a banner image that you have created then no matter what it does you don't need to touch or worry about anything to do with iAd.

From [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

> The ADBannerView class provides a self-contained view. Your
>   application should not subclass ADBannerView, nor should your
>   application attempt to change the behavior of the banner view. For
>   example, your application should never add subviews to a banner view.

If you are using an `ADBannerview` for anything other than displaying iAds from Apple you're doing it wrong. It seems like you want to display your own ads which are static images. The correct class to use for this is `UIImageView`. If you display your own images using an `ADBannerView` you will get rejected from the App Store.

Comment: So you mean that i should not step up the iad network using the itunes connect

Comment: Not if you're not using `ADBannerView` to display iAds. So No. By the sound of it you do not

Comment: I am using the ADBannerView,for displaying that static images